# How can I create a dynamic JSON key from a variable?

Tags: c#, json, handlebars.js, sendgrid

Our eLearning platform uses a third-party email service called SendGrid to send out our emails. We pass in a JSON object to the platform and our templates dynamically fill in values from the JSON object using Handlebars.

A typical JSON object that we pass looks like this:

```
{
   "To": "abc@xyz.com",
   "From": "zxy@abc.com",
   "Subject": "Online Course",
   "TemplateData": {
      "CourseName": "Course 1",
      "LoginPage": "https://www.login.com"
   }   
}
```

We're starting to implement multi-language support. We can add Handlebars to our template to do a condition if-then statement to dynamically populate the proper translatedd text based on the language that is passed in. So I envisioned adding a new Language key to the TemplateData with the language we passed in, as such as follows:

```
"TemplateData": {
      "CourseName": "Course 1",
      "Language": "en-US",
      "LoginPage": "https://www.login.com"
   }
```

Unfortunately, I realized that their if-else conditions in the Handlebars only support boolean comparisons, so it would have to look like this instead:

```
"TemplateData": {
      "CourseName": "Course 1",
      "en-US": true
      "LoginPage": "https://www.login.com"
   }
```

Since the language part (e.g. en-US, en-CA, fr-FR, etc.) is a variable being passed in from a stored procedure, I can't just set the language key statically in the object definition.

The deserialized object is as follows:

```
public abstract class CpiEmailMessage : IEmailMessage
{
   public string To { get; protected set; }
   protected static string FromEmail => "noreply@cpilearning.com";
   protected static string FromName => "CPI Learning";

   protected Dictionary<string, string> CustomArgs(int emailLogId) => new 
                      Dictionary<string, string>
   {
       { "SystemSource", "HoneyBee.Integrations" },
       { "Env", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Env") },
       { "EmailLogId", $"{emailLogId}" }
   };

   public abstract EmailSendRequest ToEmailSendRequest(int emailLogId);
   public abstract EmailLog ToLogEmailCommandRequest(int currentUser, bool sent);
 }

public class PurchaseEmailMessage : CpiEmailMessage
{
    private string Subject { get; }
    public string CourseName { get; }
    public string CourseLanguage { get; set; }
    public string LoginPage { get; set; }
    
    public string Url { get; }
    public string OnlineOnly { get; }

    private static EmailType MessageTemplateKey => EmailType.PURCHASE;

 public PurchaseEmailMessage(string to, string subject, string courseName, string courseLanguage, string loginPage, string cmsURL, string onlineOnly)
 {
      To = to;
      Subject = subject;
      CourseName = courseName;
      CourseLanguage = courseLanguage;
      LoginPage = loginPage;
      Url= cmsURL;
      OnlineOnly = onlineOnly;
  }

  public override EmailSendRequest ToEmailSendRequest(int emailLogId)
  {
       return new EmailSendRequest
       {
            To = To,
            FromEmail = FromEmail,
            FromName = FromName,
            Subject = Subject,
            MessageTemplateKey = MessageTemplateKey,
            TemplateData = new
            {
                Course = CourseName,
                LoginUrl = LoginPage
            },
            CustomArgs = CustomArgs(emailLogId),
            EmailLogId = emailLogId,
            Categories = new List<string> { "Seat Purchase" }
        };
    }
}
```

How can I take the language variable (en-US) and make it a key in TemplateData with a 'true' value?

Comment: How are you generating the JSON right now?

Comment: "We can add Handlebars to our template to do a condition if-then statement to dynamically populate the proper translatedd text based on the language that is passed in." - please post an example of your Handlebars templates - I hope you're not embedding localized strings directly in the template... if so, then this is an "X/Y Problem" because **that's not how you're supposed to use Handlebars to localize content**.

Comment: @Dai - SendGrid has certain HandleBars functionality built into it when creating templates, so my thought was that our email template would be like this:

{{#if fr-CA}}
    [French Canadian translated HTML]
{{else if de-DE}}
    [German translated HTML]
{{else}}
   [English translated HTML]
{{/if}}

Comment: Here's a link to their documentation for it: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars/#conditional-statements

Comment: Ah, I see that SendGrid's own example [uses that approach](https://github.com/sendgrid/email-templates/blob/master/dynamic-templates/different-languages/different_languages.html) - ugh. I'm disappointed that they're doing it that way.

Comment: But still, please demonstrate how you're generating the JSON you send to SendGrid.

Comment: @Dai I'm just creating a class object with the to, from, subject line, and an object called TemplateData that contains all of the data that I need to use handlebars to replace items in the template, and this TemplateData object would have the "en-US": true property in it.  Then I'm just serializing that object as a new Message and sending that through the SendGrid API

Comment: So if you want to add new fields then subclass that class, add the properties, then serialize.

Comment: @Dai - I added additional object structure details to the original post so you can see, but it's basically already subclassed out.